# How to open multiple files in explorer at the same time?

Tags: c, winapi

It is a little tricky to describe my question, but I'll try my best.

First, I am developing a Multi-Document-Interface app using C and WinAPI. My program is able to parse command line arguments to open multiple files. I put this string:
*"X:\MyAppName.exe" "%1"*
under the open with command list of the txt files so that now I can right click any .txt files in Windows Explorer and open it with my app. However, when I select multiple files, the explorer runs command *"X:\MyAppName.exe" "%1"* multiple times so that multiple instances of my app are started.

But wait!  **That's not the most tricky part. Instead, it is that my app treats opening a single file and opening multiple files at a time as two different things with seperate visual styles.** I know the idea of keeping one instance running at a time (though I don't know the C code to implement it). But I don't know how to tell the difference between open several files one by one and opening multiple files at the same time.

I hope I make it clear.

Comment: You have multiple options. Perhaps the prettiest is to [say that your app can accept data objects containing multiple objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/03/10006065.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Registry like you currently are, you will not be able to directly differentiate between multiple files from single files.  Each requested file will start a new copy of your app, as you have already noticed.  If you implement single-instancing (which is not that hard to do), what you could do is detect when the first file is requested and start a short timer, then have each subsequent file reset that timer.  When it finally elapses, check how many files you collected and act on them as needed.

A better, and preferred, solution is to instead create an out-of-process COM object in your app that implements the `IDropTarget` interface.  Windows will then be able to funnel file information through a single entry point into your app.  Your app will not have to care where the information is coming from.  You will be able to support not only multiple files at a time, but even different formats of file information (Windows could pass you just the file names, or it could pass you the actual file data itself).

Windows will construct a single `IDataObject` object to hold whatever file information is needed, and will then pass it to your `IDropTarget` object.  If your app is already running, COM will be able to access your existing `IDropTarget` object.  If your app is not already running, COM will automatically start your app before then accessing its `IDropTarget` object.  Either way, once it is running, your `IDropTarget` can look at whatever data is passed to it and decide whether to accept it or reject it.

If you register your COM object's `CLSID` as a `DropTarget` for the desired file extensions, users will be able to double-click on such files, or select such files and press Enter, and they will be passed to your `IDropTarget` object.

If you register an `AppPath` for your app and then register the `CLSID` as a `DropTarget` for it, users will be able to drag files, regardless of extension, onto your app's exe file itself, and they will be passed to your `IDropTarget` object.

If you use the same COM object with the `RegisterDragDrop()` function, users will be able to drag files, regardless of extension, onto your app's UI directly, and they will be passed to your `IDropTarget` object.

Comment: Thank you. This is a really wonderful answer! But one thing I'm confused: you said "users will be able to double-click on such files, or select such files and press Enter", will this override the default open with command in the registry? Or I need to modify the registry too?

Comment: It does not replace it, it enhances it. You still have to create a default verb for the file extension in order for a double-click to do something, but you can specify a "DropTarget" for the verb instead of a "command" (the Shell also supports a third option for invoking DDE, but `IDropTarget` is preferred over that).